# javascript array and php array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to get all values into php and print each value with its value.

**Javascript array**

```
var search_results =[{"products_sold":"94","cyl_lim_up":4,"sph_lim_up":8,"search_face_shapes":    ["Oblong"],"pdp_url_base":"eyeglasses","prod_id":"3809","default_psku_id":"7921","brand_name":"Ray-    Ban","scene7_company_code":"luxottica","scene7_url_suffix":"","search_sizes":["Medium"],"base_type_friendly":["Glasses"],"sph_lim_dn":-    10,"type_name":"Full-Rim Plastic","max_price":179,"prescription_type":"Progressive\/Multifocal","product_name":"Ray-Ban RX5228","search_genders":    ["Unisex","Women"],"min_price":179,"url_key":"Ray-Ban-RX5228","pd_lim_dn":-100,"base_product_url":["\/glasses\/Ray-Ban-    RX5228"],"pd_lim_up":100,"cyl_lim_dn":-4,"scene7_model_code":"rx5228","scene7_brand_code":"rayban","is_completely_out_of_stock":"0","search_shapes":    ["Square"],"featured_sort_rank":9999,"simple_sort_rank":9999,"active_psku_id":"7921","insurance":null,"show_specialty_lens":true,"skus":    [{"price":"179.00","regular_price":"179.00","scene7_swatch_code":"black","psku_id":"7920","sku_index":0,"supports_rx":"0","polarized":"0","image_code":"luxot    tica_rayban_rx5228_black","upc":"805289445913","color_description":"Shiny Black","specialty_lens_option":"NULL","web_vto_available":"1","frame_weight":30,"lens_width":50,"lens_height":35,"bridge_size":17,"temple_size":140,"vto_path":"Ray-Ban~RX5228-092764cb6bae0671\/805289445913"},{"price":"179.00","regular_price":"179.00","scene7_swatch_code":"tortoise","psku_id":"7921","sku_index":1,"supports_rx":"0","polarized":"0","image_code":"luxottica_rayban_rx5228_tortoise","upc":"805289445890","color_description":"Dark Havana","specialty_lens_option":"NULL","web_vto_available":"1","frame_weight":30,"lens_width":50,"lens_height":35,"bridge_size":17,"temple_size":140,"vto_path":"Ray-Ban~RX5228-092764cb6bae0671\/805289445890"},{"price":"179.00","regular_price":"179.00","scene7_swatch_code":"blue","psku_id":"8220","sku_index":2,"supports_rx":"0","polarized":"0","image_code":"luxottica_rayban_rx5228_blue","upc":"713132453728","color_description":"Blue","specialty_lens_option":"NULL","web_vto_available":"1","frame_weight":30,"lens_width":50,"lens_height":35,"bridge_size":17,"temple_size":140,"vto_path":"Ray-Ban~RX5228-092764cb6bae0671\/713132453728"},{"price":"179.00","regular_price":"179.00","scene7_swatch_code":"red","psku_id":"9185","sku_index":3,"supports_rx":"0","polarized":"0","image_code":"luxottica_rayban_rx5228_red","upc":"713132453780","color_description":"Dark Red Transparent","specialty_lens_option":"NULL","web_vto_available":"1","frame_weight":30,"lens_width":50,"lens_height":35,"bridge_size":17,"temple_size":140,"vto_path":"Ray-Ban~RX5228\/713132453780"},{"price":"179.00","regular_price":"179.00","scene7_swatch_code":"black2","psku_id":"9969","sku_index":4,"supports_rx":"0","polarized":"0","image_code":"luxottica_rayban_rx5228_black2","upc":"805289445876","color_description":"Black on Texture","specialty_lens_option":"NULL","web_vto_available":"0","frame_weight":30,"lens_width":50,"lens_height":35,"bridge_size":17,"temple_size":140,"vto_path":null}],"skuCount":12},{"products_sold":"87","cyl_lim_up":4,"sph_lim_up":8,"search_face_shapes":["Round","Oval"],"pdp_url_base":"eyeglasses","prod_id":"4877","default_psku_id":"10822","brand_name":"Oakley","scene7_company_code":"oakley","scene7_url_suffix":"","search_sizes":["Large"],"base_type_friendly":["Glasses"],"sph_lim_dn":-10,"type_name":"Full-Rim Plastic","max_price":160,"prescription_type":"Progressive\/Multifocal","product_name":"Oakley Tailspin Large","search_genders":["Men"],"min_price":112,"url_key":"Oakley-Tailspin-Large","pd_lim_dn":-100,"base_product_url":["\/glasses\/Oakley-Tailspin-Large"],"pd_lim_up":100,"cyl_lim_dn":-4,"scene7_model_code":"tailspinlarge","scene7_brand_code":"oakley","is_completely_out_of_stock":"0","search_shapes":["Rectangle"],"featured_sort_rank":9999,"simple_sort_rank":9999,"active_psku_id":"10822","insurance":null,"show_specialty_lens":true,"skus":[{"price":"112.00","regular_price":"160.00","scene7_swatch_code":"grey","psku_id":"10822","sku_index":0,"supports_rx":"0","polarized":"0","image_code":"oakley_oakley_tailspinlarge_grey","message":"30% Off","upc":"700285642840","color_description":"Satin Smoke","specialty_lens_option":"NULL","web_vto_available":"0","frame_weight":20,"lens_width":55,"lens_height":33,"bridge_size":18,"temple_size":140,"vto_path":null},{"price":"160.00","regular_price":"160.00","scene7_swatch_code":"gunmetal","psku_id":"10872","sku_index":1,"supports_rx":"0","polarized":"0","image_code":"oakley_oakley_tailspinlarge_gunmetal","upc":"700285831138","color_description":"Black Fade","specialty_lens_option":"NULL","web_vto_available":"0","frame_weight":25,"lens_width":55,"lens_height":33,"bridge_size":18,"temple_size":140,"vto_path":null},{"price":"160.00","regular_price":"160.00","scene7_swatch_code":"black3","psku_id":"10873","sku_index":2,"supports_rx":"0","polarized":"0","image_code":"oakley_oakley_tailspinlarge_black3","upc":"700285830988","color_description":"Satin Black & Orange","specialty_lens_option":"NULL","web_vto_available":"0","frame_weight":20,"lens_width":55,"lens_height":33,"bridge_size":18,"temple_size":140,"vto_path":null}],"skuCount":3}
```

I used this script for getting array values but not successfully
php code:

```
 $html = file_get_html('http://localhost/scrapping/web.html');

$ctr=0;

$span_cat = $html->find("<script type='text/javascript'>");

//preg_match_all("/\[(\{(.*)\})\]/", $span_cat[0], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
preg_match_all("/\[(\{(.*)\})\]/", $span_cat[0], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $val) {
echo "matched: " . $val[0] . "\n";
}
```

Please help me to resolve this, I will be very thankful

Comment: That looks like a job for [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: can you explain me more how can we do this with json basically there is lots of brackets and commas. please help on this